# Switch Spyder Environment without installing spyder at each environment

Tags: python, spyder, conda

I am using multiple conda environments, and use Spyder as my IDE. These environments often have the same python version, and differ based on installed packages (packages not used by spyder).

I looked how to run spyder in a certain environment, and the answers i found all state that i first have to install spyder in that environment and then run it.

However, this of course requires extra space used on my computer. Is there a way to use spyder in different conda environments, without installing spyder multiple times (or maybe just once per python version)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the quick answer is only to install the **spyder-kernel** package within the desired conda environment. You don't need to install the whole spyder package again and again.

Comment: As @andrea explained an easy solution for solving this problem, it's worth mentioning that if you do that, some functionality like "Variable Explorer" may not work correctly and might get the error message "Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.", thus, I suggest you reconsider using this method.

Answer (score 6):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We added some improvements in our 3.3 versions to help users deal more easily with multiple environments. Please see this [blog post](https://www.spyder-ide.org/blog/release-spyder-330/) for the details, in particular the section called *Even more fixes and refinements with Spyder 3.3.1*.

*Note*: A [little bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7674) that affects this surfaced after we released 3.3.1, just in case you find that problem too. A fix will be available in 3.3.2, and [more improvements](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Roadmap) on how to handle conda environments are planned for Spyder 4, to be released in 2019.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the blog post worked for me. If you would add these details to your answer (install spyder kernel, and change path to interpreter) i will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: This answer points to very useful information, but I would not call it an answer.

Comment: @Carlos I agree with adr: I am still confused. Let's say I have en environment, X, that only has numpy as a dependency, but want to run Spyder as my IDE, without installing Spyder and all its dependencies, in environment X. Is this possible? Is this a separate question?

Comment: @eric, yes, it is possible. Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to learn how to do that.

Comment: ok I just have to install `spyder-kernels` within X, not full-blown Spyder. Thanks!